# Enabling traceId in ballerina services

Tags: ballerina

Is there any build in apis to enable traceId or correlationId to group the logs in ballerina?  Also How we can pass the traceId from one service to another service. Are there anything ballerina provides by default? Or do we need to write them in the services?

Answer (score 1):

Please enable tracing by adding following to Config.toml file

```
[ballerina.observe]
tracingEnabled=true
tracingProvider="jaeger"
```

Then import jaeger in your service

```
import ballerinax/jaeger as _;
```

Then you will see the traceId and spanId stamped with logs. The traceId is automatically propagated among ballerina services.

Please refer to https://ballerina.io/learn/observe-ballerina-programs/#distributed-tracing for more information on tracing.